# map hash keys in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, key

If I have a hash

```
{"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3}
```

What is the best way to map the keys to get the array:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

Comment: Is the result expected to be *ordered* in any way? Because there can be equivalent hashes (with more than one key), for which the results of Hash#keys is not guaranteed to yield the same sequence order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3}.keys #=> ["one", "two", "three"]
```

The [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-keys) is awesome for discovering answers to questions like these.

If the question is "how do I get X data from object of type Y?", reading through the docs for object type Y should be the first place you go.

Answer (score 5):

```
{"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3}.keys
```